# Enabling HttpPost on web service asmx returns arrays rather than lists

Tags: arrays, web-services, list, asmx, http-post

On my client application I want to get some objects back as generic lists from my web service. It works fine, until I add this to my web.config:

```
<system.web>
<webServices>
    <protocols>
        <add name="HttpGet"/>
        <add name="HttpPost"/>
       <remove name="HttpSoap12" />
    </protocols>
</webServices>
</system.web>
```

After I add this, it doesn't serialise returned objects as generic lists anymore, but instead as arrays! Removing this from the web.config fixes it but I want to disable soap 1.2 and need the other 2 lines to make it work for my client application.

Why would it do this?

Comment: iv tried adding "httpsoap" too but that has no effect.

Comment: Web services return XML, not either arrays nor lists. It's a question of whether different XML is returned, or whether the client deserializes the same XML differently.